# convert javascript spread syntax to older version code

Tags: javascript, node.js, spread-syntax

I have a piece of code which uses spread syntax.

On my main server, the node js version is 0.10. For some reason, it's not possible to upgrade node js. So I'm converting all the arrow functions such that they are compatible with the old version of node js. I'm not able to convert the spread operator.
I tried with `Object.assign` but it keeps showing syntax error. I'm confused on how to convert spread operator to normal javascript code.

Here is my code  :

```
senddata = Array.from({ ...data, length: Math.max(...Object.keys(data)) });
```

I'm finding it really confusing to convert this. In fact I'm just not able to understand where to add Object.assign and how to fix the syntax errors regarding it.

For arrow function I converted them like this:

with arrow function :

```
dag.get('obj')
      .then((data) => {

        run();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

without arrow function

```
dag.get('obj')
      .then(function(data)  {

        run();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

But not able to convert spread syntax.

This is what I tried :

```
Object.assign({data},length: Math.max(Object.assign({Object},keys(data))
```

Moreover, how can I write the same code without using spread syntax or Object.assign ?

After referring to the answers and suggestions posted below,here is the code :

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }

function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (Symbol.iterator in Object(iter) || Object.prototype.toString.call(iter) === "[object Arguments]") return Array.from(iter); }

function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } }

senddata = Array.from({ ...data,
  length: Math.max.apply(Math, _toConsumableArray(Object.keys(data)))
});
```

But I still get an error for `...data`

Comment: *"I tried with `Object.assign` but it keeps showing syntax error"* - could you show a [mcve] of that? That's how transpilers like Babel convert spreads.

Comment: post `data` value

Comment: It's not helpful to show the code you *have* successfully converted, you're asking about the bit you *haven't* - show *that* attempt.

Comment: added the code for spread operator

Comment: Babel has an [online transpiler that will basically do this for you](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=M4UwdgJhCGAu0AIC8CCCAnd0CeA6AZugPYC2AFAN4K40zwA0CANuAOawAWAXAgLJwdcJaAA8yNXAHkARgCsQAY1i4A1iGzAydaAEodCAL46A3EA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.3)

Comment: Or better yet, just [use Babel](https://babeljs.io)

Comment: how can i write that same code without the spread operator?

Comment: Liam gave you the answer. Node 0.10, is that from 2009?

Comment: yea it's from 2009. It's an old server running some other scripts which will stop working if I upgrade node.

Comment: I checked Liam's answer but in the output, the spread operator is still there.

Comment: When you say that it is not possible to update Node, do you mean technically not possible, or you *should* not update it ? If the problem is technical, have you tried NVM (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) ?

Comment: I will try to implement Liam's answer and will let you know

Comment: It is technically possible to update node but I should not update it

Comment: @node_man You need to select ENV_PRESET on the left, then check Node and configure your version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel creates this for your line of code with the correct preset:

```
"use strict";

function _toConsumableArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }

function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (Symbol.iterator in Object(iter) || Object.prototype.toString.call(iter) === "[object Arguments]") return Array.from(iter); }

function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } }

function _objectSpread(target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i] != null ? arguments[i] : {}; var ownKeys = Object.keys(source); if (typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols === 'function') { ownKeys = ownKeys.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).filter(function (sym) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym).enumerable; })); } ownKeys.forEach(function (key) { _defineProperty(target, key, source[key]); }); } return target; }

function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) { if (key in obj) { Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { value: value, enumerable: true, configurable: true, writable: true }); } else { obj[key] = value; } return obj; }

senddata = Array.from(_objectSpread({}, data, {
  length: Math.max.apply(Math, _toConsumableArray(Object.keys(data)))
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

`{ ...obj }` object spread syntax is syntactic sugar for `Object.assign({}, obj)`.

`Math.max(...iterable)` is regular spread syntax, for function arguments it's translated to `apply` call.

It should be:

```
Object.assign({}, data, { length: Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data))) })
```